# Why is the numberOfRowsInSection being called multiple times for only one section?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

```
// Variable and ViewDidLoad

var auxRow = 0
var auxSection = 0   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

//Number Of Sections, only one section

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        auxSection += 1
        print("times section: ", auxSection)
        return 1
    }
```

//Number Of Rows

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    auxRow += 1
    print("times row: ", auxRow)
    return 2
}
```

// TableView Configure the cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let textCellIdentifier = "cellText"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let variable : String = indexPath.row.description
    cell.textLabel?.text = variable
    return cell

}
```

Output:

```
    times section:  1
    times row:  1
    times section:  2
    times row:  2
    times section:  3
    times row:  3
    times section:  4
    times row:  4
```

The method `numberOfRowsInSection` is being called 4 times. Why is that happening?

Comment: I'm not understand why enter 4 times in the method numberOfRowsInSection. I have only one section

Comment: @Lamar: OP is asking why the numberOfRowsInSection method executes 4 times, because he has only 1 section (not 4 section, so theoretically it that method should be executed only one time)

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection method executes 4 times, because? What is the reason?

Comment: does it matter? is it causing you a problem? only someone with knowledge of the Apple source code can tell you really...

Comment: This `numberOfRowsInSection` method would return the number of row for your tableview.. since you have 4 objects into your data structure. It would return 4 rows

Comment: @Lamar yes but it's calling `numberOfRowsInSection` 4 times... I would understand if it called `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ... Not sure on the question from the OP but this is just to address your comment :)

Answer (score 6):

Apple makes no guarantees how often UIKit may call one of your delegate methods. They own the framework. We can expect them to cache that value but nothing requires them to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a breakpoint inside your `numberOfRowsInSection` method to see what it is being used for internally. There is no reason why it shouldn't be called multiple times, as it is called any time the tableview internally needs to know how many rows it has. It is called 4 times because Apple's tableview code needs to know, at 4 different times, how many rows are in your one section.

Comment: It is called 4 times numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView -> 
times section:  1
times row:  1
times section:  2
times row:  2
times section:  3
times row:  3
times section:  4
times row:  4

Comment: @PedroMeira im sorry but I dont understand what that is supposed to mean

Comment: Both those methods can be called any number of times depending on how the tableview is using them internally. It is not 100% tied to the number of rows or sections your tableview has.

Comment: I have only one section, the method numberOfRowsInSection should only be called once, why it is called 4 times ? I changed the question code and the method numberOfSectionsInTableView is called 4 times. What is the reason? I do not understand why this happens and wanted to see if it's me I'm doing something wrong

Comment: "I have only one section, the method numberOfRowsInSection should only be called once" is just not true. Your fundamental assumption right there is wrong. What is right is "I have only one section, the method numberOfRowsInSection should be called as many times as Apple's tableview code wants to call it, which, in my case, is 4."